# File managers and windows shares

Tags: windows, cifs

I would like to be able to use an interactive file manager to move files around on Windows shared folders. I can successfully issue "sudo mount -t cifs ..." and then use an interactive file manager both for an old version 1.0 Windows machine and a current Windows 10 machine. However none of the file managers tried so far will successfully perform the mount or, in some cases, even show the presence of the Windows machine. The file managers are being used as a normal user rather than root. Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: The behavior is expected. You can use Disks to change the mount options or edit the `fstab` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a bit of a probe and the problem seems to be with the gio program the file managers seem to be using to mount files as a normal user rather than root. The program prompts for a remote user name and password when it is not required and I didn't seem to be able to get passed it. Anyone? It was reported as a bug 2 years ago https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gvfs/-/issues/405. To check I setup a windows share that required a userid and password and it worked fine.